# Sphinx with Matlab does not generate documentation

Tags: python, matlab, python-sphinx

I have important MATLAB libraries and I want to document them through Sphinx. The data structure more or less is as follows

```
|- Matlab
      |- scripts
      |- functions
|- docs
      |- source
      |- conf.py
      |- index.rst
      |- Makefile
      |- make.bat
              |- ...
```

Relevant lines in conf.py are

```
import os

extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinxcontrib.matlab'
]

this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('Matlab'))
matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(this_dir, '..'))
primary_domain = 'mat'
```

When running `make html` from `/docs`? I don't get any errors but no documentation is generated.

logs

```
Running Sphinx v5.0.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
no targets are out of date.
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in _build\html.
```

Comment: Are you using any of the directives mentioned here? https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/matlabdomain#roles-and-directives

Comment: yes, but so far it is not working

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Create a `docs` folder in the Matlab folder, Run `sphinx-quickstart` that will create the necessary file. Edit conf.py with the details above. No generation for the matlab code

Comment: https://devanginiblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/16/how-to-properly-document-matlab-code/ Sounds like you need some extra steps.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of `sphinxcontrib.matlab` and would gladly help, but as others has noted, we need some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.rst file (or other .rst file that index.rst points to), you'll need a directive for it to key off of. Something like this may work in your index.rst:

```
functions
=========

.. mat:automodule:: functions
    :members:
    :show-inheritance:
    :undoc-members:
```

I highly recommend looking at the code examples in the [matlabdomain github](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/matlabdomain/tree/master/tests/test_docs_automodule).

It also looks like your matlab source dir is off a little. Based on your structure I would assume it'd be this:

```
matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'Matlab'))
```

And one more thing; if you want to pull the comments out of your code headers, you also need to run the autodoc at some point. The sphinx quickstart will put that execution in the make.bat file, or you can run it manually. I have a python script that runs it all (rather than make). However the call is:

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -M -o {doc_dir} {code_dir}
```

where for you (if running at your base dir) {doc_dir} is ./docs and {code_dir} would be ./Matlab